# Creating oriented centerlines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

How do I create oriented centerlines in QGIS as in the following image:

[image]

Input data is a shapefile of irregular polygons as in the image below and available on the following link:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fAS3BDDis6z154L0nJVelWJoKzU04lFN?usp=sharing

[image]

Figure 1: Shapefile of irregular polygons

Secondly, Minimum bounding box tool was used to create a bounding box ('perfect rectangles') around each polygon as in the image below and available on the following link:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tr3umzfsE2dBVna9J1tYE89eoe3Vc0gR?usp=sharing.

QGIS > Processing Toolbox > Vector Geometry > Minimum bounding box

[image]

I need to create oriented centerlines to produce rows of lines as in the example image below:

[image]

Comment: Where the orientation should come from?

Comment: It is not clear how you need to generate oriented centerlines. It should be simply diagonal instead of horizontal under certain conditions?

Comment: The global orientation of centerlines of all vectors present in the tile must be calculated first.

Comment: So the oriented centerlines all have the same azimuth - thus: they all lie on the same line? Calculation of global orientation is not part of this question, you have already solved this, haven't you? In any case, due to the focused question and answer form here on GIS SE, please post another question for this, if not yet solved.

Comment: What can you say about the properties of your shapes: Will the line always pass through the centroid of the shapes? Are they perfect rectangles?

Comment: I have not solved it yet. All are perfect rectangles resulting from Oriented Minimum Bounding Box in QGIS >  Vector Geometry > Oriented Minimum Bounding Box

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically create a centerline (defined here: a line passing through the centroid of the polygon shape) using QGIS expressions. You might use this expression for visualization purpose only, than create a new symbol layer where you paste it: this is what is shown on the screenshot below. The other option is to create actual geometries, using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression`, pasting again the same expression.

You find the whole expression at the bottom, here is a step by step instruction how to build it:

1. Get centroid: `centroid ($geometry)`
2. Create a line that starts here with `make_line()`. The expression expects at least two arguments, both being points. The first one is the centroid from step 1. The second point will be created in step 3.
3. Generate this second point starting from the centroid (step 1) and project (shift) this point using `project(point,distance,azimuth)`. `point` is again the centroid from step 1, `distance` is an arbitrary value: be sure to select it high enough that every line overlaps the boundary of the polygon. In my example, it's `25000`, change it accordingly. `azimuth` is the azimuth (angle) of the line. I suppose you already have this value. In my case, it's `4.443010855970499` (value must be in radians, if your value is in degrees, convert it with `radians(value)` where `value` is the number in degrees).

See at the bottom how to get the angle for your polygons.

4. Now you have a line starting at the centroid and going in one direction just over the boundary of the polygon. You want the line to go in the oteher direction as well, thus use `extend(geometry,start_distance,end_distance)`. For `geometry`, use the line we created before. For start_distance, use the same distance as above (step 3) and set `end_distance` to 0: we only want to extend the line in one direction.
5. You now have the line, but want to clip it to the polygon boundary. For this, use `intersection`. You want to intersect the line created in steps 1 to 4 with each polygon (`$geometry`).

Put all together, the expression looks like:

```
intersection (
    extend (
        make_line (
            centroid ($geometry), 
            project (
                centroid ($geometry), 
                25000, 
                4.443010855970499
            )
        ),
        25000,
        0
    ),
    $geometry
)
```

[image]

**Update: how to create the mean angle**

You should get the right angle for your use case. You can use the expression `main_angle($geometry)` on your polygons to get the orientation of every polygon.

To calculate the average orientation of all rectangles in the layer, create a new field with the field calculator and introduce this expression: `main_angle($geometry)`. Than use `Menu Vector / Analysis Tools / Basic statistics for fields` with your polygon layer as input and set `Field to calculate statistics on` to the main_angle field created before (see screenshot). You get a mean angle of (rounded) 29.64 degrees = 0.5173 radians.

[image]

And this is how it looks like if you zoom in:

[image]

Comment: The result is not as expected with multiple rows of these 'perfect rectangles'

Comment: Can it be applied to achieve a row of lines @babel

Comment: The question was edited to provide more information and sample data. I hope it provides a better insight. @babel

Comment: The angle parameter is user defined.Is there a method to determine the average angle of all the lines in the layer. Breaking down the layer into further will increase the accuracy.

Comment: I meant you used radians(29.974) by selecting one rectangle from the layer. Is there a method to calculate the average orientation of all rectangles in the layer to use as input angle parameter to create the lines.

Comment: I now noticed the main_angle($geometry). Is the a method to calculate the average angle to use as input angle parameter to create the lines.

Comment: Of course: see updated answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, `main_angle($geometry)` calculates the main orientation for each polygon, see: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#add-main-angle-function-to-return-the-estimated-main-angle-of-a-geometry

Comment: The small polygons introduce the largest error, as their orientation gets close to random the smaller the patches are. So I would probably start by deleting small polygons before the calculation of `main_angle`.

Comment: @babel It is worth noting main_angle function is available as from QGIS 3.16.2. the main_angle function is behaving erroneously as illustrated in the following image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5JS7.png From link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345733/mistake-in-oriented-minimum-bounding-box-tool . From attribute table, when calculated WIDTH > HEIGHT, the short side of the box determines the angle, when WIDTH < HEIGHT the long side determines the angle. Can this be fixed with an expression.

Comment: "Be aware that [main_angle] might return unexpected results or require further processing.", see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383951/88814

Comment: @babel I elaborated on the issue on the following link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/how-to-calculate-dominant-angle-of-a-polygon-in-qgis-without-main-angle-function