# Calculating dominant angle of a polygon in QGIS without main_angle function

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, angles

How can I calculate dominant angle of a polygon in QGIS without main_angle function?

I have a shapefile of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box rectangles (accessible from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Xr_0Apg9s7s0daevIUctWTr0-WCABC83?usp=sharing) produced by using as Input Layer a shapefile of irregular polygons (accessible from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BKp5VbR1aMAzCObGprvqeL0WSMqpTX32?usp=sharing)

[image: Shapefile of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box]

**Figure 1: Shapefile of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box**

[image: Shapefile of Irregular Polygons]
**Figure 2: Shapefile of Irregular Polygons**

I need to find the main_angle of every polygon in the Oriented Minimum Bounding Box layer.

I used the main_angle function available in QGIS 3.16 onwards.

main_angle function returns the main angle of a geometry.

However, when I constructed centerlines using the centroid of the polygons (in this case rectangles) and main_angle values computed using the main_angle
function in QGIS with the following expression:

[image]

```
intersection (
extend (
    make_line (
        centroid ($geometry), 
        project (
            centroid ($geometry), 
            25000, 
            radians("main_angle")
        )
    ),
    25000,
    0
),
$geometry
```

)

Main_angle of the polygons computed with main_angle function is not at all times

the angle of longest collection of segments as in the image below encircled below:

[image]

What expression can be used such that main_angle is always the angle of longest segment of the Oriented Minimum Bounding Box in a project whereby main angle of every Oriented Minimum Bounding Box is the determining factor of accuracy of end results.

I found this comment from the following link: https://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=119435

You need an expression dependent on the height and width data:

[image]

The end result I am seeking is the overall orientation of all ploygons collectively as illustrated in the image below from the Line Direction Tool QGIS plugin. By unfortunately provides no values.

[image]

I used XLSTAT to use Principal Component Analysis but did not achieve conculsive results. Computed results and report is accessible from following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CHDfJ9poD8tk-KQLmRV8NbilZCyGtTs5?usp=sharing

Comment: Which polygon in that file is it? And how did you create those lines?

Comment: The folder contains shapefile of the polygons. In the attribute table, the main_angle field is calculated using main_angle function in QGIS 3.16. The line is drawn using centroid of each polygon and the main angle. main_angle Returns the main angle of a geometry (clockwise, in degrees from North), which represents the angle of the oriented minimal bounding rectangle which completely covers the geometry

Comment: You may use principal component analysis (PCA). Scikit-learn Python package has a PCA function. See: https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dfg/ProbabilisticInference/old_IDAPILecture14.pdf

Comment: @Zoltan The final results I am seeking is the average main angle of orientation of the polygons collectively which visually approximates to 30 degrees.

Comment: The first eigenvector gives the direction of the first principal direction. See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cross_decomposition/plot_pcr_vs_pls.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cross-decomposition-plot-pcr-vs-pls-py

Comment: Is there an alternative I am not conversant with Scikit-learn. I found Line Direction Histogram QGIS plugin, it produced a Rose diagram as in the following image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbGyi.png but does not provide a numerical value.

Comment: @Zoltan I successfully installed FactoQGIS a GUI tool based on an R script to perform Geometric Data Analysis in a Free and Open Source GIS available from the following link:https://github.com/ESO-Rennes/FactoQGIS The image in the following link is the interface: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZmNR.pngCould you advise on the parameters to set

Comment: @MrXsquared I tried to add the expressions but could not get it right

Comment: @Zoltan I used XLSTAT to use Principal Component Analysis but did not achieve conculsive results. Computed results and report is accessible from following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CHDfJ9poD8tk-KQLmRV8NbilZCyGtTs5?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is a Python example for PCA: https://github.com/OSGeoLabBp/tutorials/blob/master/english/data_processing/lessons/pca.rst

Answer (score 2):

I inspected your data, the solution is based on that. First, create a new field `longest` that evaluates which side of your rectangle is the longest, `width` or `height`. Use this expression in the field calculator: `if ( "width" > "height" , 'width', 'height')`.

Than you can create the centerline using this expression with `Geometry generator` or `Geometry by expression` as you already have a field `angle` in your data that, depending on which one is the longest side, can be used to create what you want:

```
intersection (
    $geometry, 
    extend (
        make_line (
            centroid ($geometry), 
            project ( 
                centroid ( $geometry ), 
                20,  
                if  (
                    "longest" =  'width' , 
                    radians ("angle"-90 ), 
                    radians ("angle" )
                )
            )
        ), 
    20,
    0
    )
)
```

[image]

If you want to get the mean value for the angle (azimuth) of all these lines, create a new layer `centerline` using `Geometry by expression` with the expression from above. On this line layer, create a new field `azimuth` using `field calculator` that calculates the angle of each line with this expression:

```
degrees (
    azimuth (
        start_point ($geometry), 
        end_point ($geometry)
    )
)
```

Now, you can use `Menu Vector / Analysis tools / Basic statistics for fields` on the `centerline` layer and setting the field `azimuth` as input (see screenshot below). The mean value for all centerlines, calculated with your data and according to this tool is `39.470817687074835`.

[image]

Comment: With the Rose Diagram and visually, the main orientation of all polygons collectively can be seen to be in specific range which approximates to around 30 degrees. Can an additional filter be added to force (override  "width" > "height" , 'width', 'height') such that all centerlines are drawn with respect to the collective orientation of all polygons. A suggestion can be a rotation of 90 degrees based on a condition.

Comment: Of course you can use any custom value for the angle. Just paste this value in the expression instead of `"angle"` - see the result here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsH9G.png - is that the result you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, correction to my last comment: if you use a fixed value (e.g. 30 degrees), you should not use the `-90` part of the expression - you could replace the whole `if` clause by `radians (30)` (or, alternatively, just delete the `9` from `90` , thus: `radians ("angle"-0),`

Comment: In the sent image, the lines are oriented in the overall direction of all polygons collectively, but are no more centerlines. I meant to say a filter to draw centerlines overriding the deciding factor width > height and width < height. The decision factor is which centerline would be closest to the overall orientation of all polygons collectively

Comment: Do you want to calculate the angle for all lines as they can be seen in the screenshot of my answer (not the comment) and than get the mean value?

Comment: Updated my answer: is that the solution you're looking for?

Comment: I formulated the objective in a new question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384445/how-to-draw-centerlines-of-oriented-minimum-bounding-box-in-the-orientation-clos

Comment: You should rather update the original question. The new questions risks to be closed as a duplicate. So the updated answer is not what you're looking for?

Comment: The objective is different in the new question.

Comment: So you want one of two possible centerlines per rectangle. With centerlines you mean lines passing through the Midpoints, **not** the corners: http://www.surfandcode.in/2014/10/rectangle-centerlines-part-01.html - Right?
To apply this: in the expression in my answer above, replace the condition in the `if`-clause from now `"longest" =  'width'` with: `"angle" >30 and "angle"<120`. Than you get the following result (red lines): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ioDs.png
Is this what you want? If not, it would help if you would draw on my screenshot to indicate how the lines should look.

Comment: main_angle function returns the main angle of a geometry. This question is in respect to centerlines (line passing through midpoints and centroid) of each polygon. The centerline of each polygon drawn is based on the criteria: angle of centerline is closest to overall orientation of all polygons in the layer. E.g. When the overall orientation= 30, If centerline across shortest segment of rectangle is 40, and angle of centerline across longest segment of same rectangle is (40 + 90) degrees that is 130 degrees since it is a perfect rectangle, the centerline with angle 40 degrees is drawn

Comment: Kindly refer to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3vzP.png Green lines are corrected lines, Ticked blue are correct one, crossed blue the centerline drawn needs rotation

Comment: OK, see this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA1yr.png - green line = 30 degrees reference line. I only changed the `if` clause again to: `"angle" >=90 and "angle"<=180`. You could try to change the values manually, if doing it in geometry generator, you can observe changes in realtime. Feel free to mark errors again in the screenshot. I hope we come closer to a satisfying solution?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected result. I believe you should post it as an answer to question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384445/how-to-draw-centerlines-of-oriented-minimum-bounding-box-in-the-orientation-clos It may be of great value. What needs to be changed in the if clause for different angle for example 75 degrees.

Comment: OK, posted the answer there.