# How to draw centerlines of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box in the orientation closest to orientation of all polygons collectively in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector

How to draw centerlines of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box in the orientation closest to overall orientation of all polygons collectively in the layer in QGIS?

I have a shapefile of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box rectangles (accessible from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Xr_0Apg9s7s0daevIUctWTr0-WCABC83?usp=sharing) produced by using Oriented Minimum Bounding Box Tool in QGIS and as Input Layer: a shapefile of irregular polygons (accessible from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BKp5VbR1aMAzCObGprvqeL0WSMqpTX32?usp=sharing)

[image: Shapefile of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box]

**Figure 1: Shapefile of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box**

[image: Shapefile of Irregular Polygons]
**Figure 2: Shapefile of Irregular Polygons**

I constructed centerlines using the centroid of the polygons (in this case rectangles) and angle values in the attribute table of Oriented Minimum Bounding Box using the following expression:

[image]

The overall orientation of all polygons collectively as illustrated in the Rose Diagram below from the Line Direction Tool QGIS plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LineDirectionHistogram/ approximates to 30 degrees.

[image]

I am seeking to draw the centerlines of each polygon in the overall orientation of all polygons in the layer collectively.

That is, the deciding factor whether the centerline will be drawn either across the shortest segment or the longest segment of each polygon, will be the angle of the resulting centerline.

For example, let assume that the overall orientation of polygons collectively is 30 degrees.

Angle of Centerline of polygon across shortest segment is 40 degrees,

Angle of Centerline of polygon across longest segment is 130 degrees,

**The centerline of polygon with angle 40 degrees is drawn.** 40 degrees being closer to 30 degrees, which is the overall angle of all polygons collectively.

This rule is applied for each centerline in each polygon in the layer when drawn.

Comment: main_angle function returns the main angle of a geometry. This question is in respect to centerlines (line passing through midpoints and centroid) of each polygon. The centerline of each polygon drawn is based on the criteria: angle of centerline is closest to overall orientation of all polygons in the layer. E.g. When the overall orientation= 30, If centerline across shortest segment of rectangle is 40, and angle of centerline across longest segment of same rectangle is (40 + 90) degrees that is 130 degrees since it is a perfect rectangle, the centerline with angle 40 degrees is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the data you provided, you can create the centerline using the following expression with `Geometry generator` or `Geometry by expression`. You already have a field `angle` in your data  that can be used to create the line. It needs to be rotated by 90 degrees depending on the value of the `angle` field from you attributes:

```
intersection (
    $geometry, 
    extend (
        make_line (
            centroid ($geometry), 
            project ( 
                centroid ( $geometry ), 
                20,  
                if  (
                    "angle" > 90 and "angle"< 180, 
                    radians ("angle"-90 ), 
                    radians ("angle" )
                )
            )
        ), 
    20,
    0
    )
)
```

See the result - red lines are centerlinse, the green line represents a reference line with angle (azimuth) of 30 degrees:

[image]

Comment: Is provided expression applicable for all posible reference angles or it needs to be altered for each quadrant.

Comment: It should work for each quadrant as it is based on the angle and this does not depend on the quadrant. I did not test it, however. But what you have to do is to adapt the `if` clause `"angle" > 90 and "angle" < 180` - and I don't know exactly how you calculated the `angle` field. So but you can test it, modifying these values.

Comment: The angle field and values is created by Oriental Minimum Bounding Box tool in QGIS

Comment: @ babel I noticed some angles (generated automatically by the Oriented Minimum Bounding Box tool in QGIS) in the attribute table of the polygons are wrong. For e.g. Polygon ID: 2536, angle is 120 degrees as in the screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/WOQU2.png. While it should be around 30. This induces errors of accuracy of mean angle. The angle field needs to be recalcalculated with a condition taking into account the overall orientation of all polygons. There are 2 possibilities: along the longest edge or along the shortest edge. There will be 90 degrees difference since they are at right angles.

Comment: OK, I ser. I guess this is not a question, just a remark, right?